# Does a 3rd-level Wolf Totem barbarian get advantage against enemies when an ally is within 5 feet of the enemy?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, advantage-and-disadvantage, rage

The [Path of the Totem Warrior](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheTotemWarrior) barbarian's 3rd-level Wolf [Totem Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#TotemSpirit-100) feature (PHB, p. 50) says:

> While you're raging, your friends have advantage on melee attack rolls against any creature within 5 feet of you that is hostile to you.

Does this benefit apply to the Barbarian as well, if an ally is within 5 feet of an enemy?

Answer (score 18):

## No, Wolf Totem Spirit does not grant advantage to the barbarian

The [Path of the Totem Warrior](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheTotemWarrior) barbarian's 3rd-level Wolf [Totem Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#TotemSpirit-100) feature (PHB, p. 50) says (emphasis mine):

> While you're raging, **your friends have advantage** on melee attack rolls against any creature within 5 feet of you that is hostile to you. The spirit of the wolf makes you a leader of hunters.

The feature only does what it says. It grants advantage on melee attack roll to your friends, provided the target is within 5 feet of you. The additional flavour text indicates that this feature is intended to make you a leader, supporting others with your powers. **You can use [Reckless Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#RecklessAttack-53) to gain advantage for yourself.**

This feature is in contrast to the [Wolf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/wolf)'s Pack Tactics feature which says:

> The wolf has advantage on attack rolls against a creature if at least one of the wolf's allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn't incapacitated.

The similarity of the flavour and mechanics of these features is likely the cause of your confusion. They are not the same feature however and have different effects.

Answer (score 7):

## No - *your* presence grants advantage to your *friends*

The wording there gives no indication that this feature affects you personally, so there's no reason to believe that it would. Lets compare it to the other totem spirit options at the same level:

> **Bear**. While raging, ***you*** have resistance to all damage except psychic damage. The spirit of the bear makes you tough enough to stand up to any punishment.

- this option affects ***you***.

> **Eagle**. While you're raging and aren't wearing heavy armor, ***other creatures*** have disadvantage on opportunity attack rolls ***against you*** and ***you*** can use the Dash action as a bonus action on your turn. The spirit of the eagle makes you into a predator who can weave through the fray with ease.

- this option affects ***other creatures*** who are making opportunity attacks against you, and ***you*** directly allowing you a bonus action dash.

> **Wolf**. While you're raging, ***your friends*** have advantage on melee attack rolls against any creature within 5 feet of you that is hostile to you. The spirit of the wolf makes you a leader of hunters.

- this option affects ***your friends***.

This all makes sense from a context point of view when you consider what's going on - you've become a 'leader of hunters' thanks to the spirit of the wolf, and so you help the hunters you lead (your friends) by your distracting presence near a foe - your enemy is distracted or hampered by your presence which gives your friends a better chance of landing a hit.

Comment: It also makes sense in the context of the Barbarian class features, since they have Reckless Attack to gain Advantage on attack rolls anyway, and Advantage doesn't stack with itself.

Comment: It might 'work' if you had 2 barbarians...both in Wolf totem spirits